# CONCAT not working in mysql56, need help running below sql

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, concatenation

So I am using MySQL56, with nodejs. When trying to create the table below, I get an error for the uniqueId line. the error i get is:

CONCAT is not valid at this position.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , 
`title` VARCHAR(255), 
`uniqueId` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT concat(Test_string, `id`) UNIQUE, 
`imageUrl` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
`description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
`createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
`updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: If by "56" you mean "5.6" then your MySQL installation is getting pretty long in the tooth.

Comment: Does MySQL support default functions in 5.6? I don't think it does. You can do that with a trigger, though.

Comment: Yup this MySQL is too old

Comment: sorry, the version is 8.0.31

Comment: You may be looking for https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html but what's test_string and I doubt if auto_increment id will have been generated when generating column is attempted,,